# Basic Site Missing Elements after Migration

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, migration

I have just migrated our website to a new server, upon doing this the site is missing background and a bunch of elements. I really know very little about PHP but from my newb diagnose it seems to me it could be in the configuration of that.

The website is - https://amandabernstein.com/

Anything to point me in the direction of resolving this or even diagnosing would be amazing. Server was Cpanel now Plesk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modern browsers have error consoles, that often can tell you a lot already, when stuff is going wrong/not working as expected. If you had checked it in this instance here (`[f12]` is usually the shortcut to open it), you would have seen several warnings/errors along the lines of _“Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.”_

Comment: Hi Cbroe, thanks you are correct indeed F12 should be the first port of call and it will be next time. Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to load static resources over HTTP when the site is viewed over HTTPS - the browser is triggering a mixed content warning and blocking the resource. Your site is not currently HTTPS-ready.

This isn't specifically about the "migration", but because you are redirecting to HTTPS.

When you move to HTTPS everything else also has to be HTTPS as well - HTTPS everywhere - not just the main target URL you see in the browser's address bar.

You probably have `http://` hardcoded in your resource URLs. This needs to be changed to `https://`.

On *modern* browsers, you can set the following HTTP response header on the initial response to instruct the browser to automatically upgrade the HTTP request to HTTPS which will avoid this browser warning.

```
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;
```

For example, you can set this in `.htaccess` with the following directive:

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

But note that this will not upgrade any outbound anchors or help old browsers that don't support this header.

Comment: Hi MrWhite, first off thanks very much for replying it is appreciated. The below did work and the rest of the content is loaded, I didn't have to manually edit anything just added the above into .htaccess and it worked so that's great. Have a wonderful day.